# How to read the results of a data layer with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

How can I read the results of a data layer with javascript? It looks like nested objects in the tag manager.

Before using the tag manager it looks like this (current values of the data layer):

```
{
   gtm:{
      start:1463690982106,
      uniqueEventId:1463690982469
   },
   event:'gtm.load',
   lftsegment:'TEST'
}
```

I tried `dataLayer.lftsegment` but that is `null`.  It is stored in the third object so I tried `dataLayer.3.lftsegment` but that is `null` as well.  I tried `dataLayer[3]` and that doesn't work either.

But I can do a console log of the entire `dataLayer` and it produces objects within and object.

*I just want to get one of those variables.*

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need those variables?

If you're working within Google Tag Manager, you can create a custom Data Layer Variable within the GTM interface, and use dot notation to identify the object you require.

If you mean that you'd like to pull that information back onto the page itself, I'm actually not sure, and would probably recommend storing that information somewhere other than the data layer.

Comment: can you give ma an example of how to use dot notation? I tried the variations with dots as in the original question but dont get anything although the object does have data. thanks